# pretrained Resnet with pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I'm newer in Pytorch and I would like to work with

```
model = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
```

Instead of this model of mnist dataset

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 20, 5, 1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(20, 50, 5, 1)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(4*4*50, 500)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(500, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2, 2)
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2, 2)
        x = x.view(-1, 4*4*50)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)


def train(args, model, device, train_loader, optimizer, epoch):
    model.train()
    for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader): # <-- now it is a distributed dataset
        model.send(data.location) # <-- NEW: send the model to the right location
        ..


model = Net().to(device)
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=args.lr) # TODO momentum is not supported at the moment

for epoch in range(1, args.epochs + 1):
    train(args, model, device, train_loader, optimizer, epoch)
    test(args, model, device, test_loader)

if (args.save_model):
    torch.save(model.state_dict(), "mnist_cnn.pt")
```

SO how can i change the code knowing that my input is an image (200,200,3)

Answer (score 0):

the input size for ResNet50 is 224x224, so you need to resize your input images to this size before passing them to the model:

```
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(224),
    transforms.ToTensor()
])

dataset = YourDataset(transform=transform)
```